# Same value displayed on running Multiple Asynctasks in parallel

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am trying call 3 JSON api's online in parallel using 3 Asynctasks.

```
private static String url1 = "http://example.com:8080/firstJson";
private static String url2 = "http://example.com:8080/secondJson";
private static String url3 = "http://example.com:8080/thirdJson";
```

In my mainActivity,the AsyncTask's are presumed to be run in parallel since I am calling
executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) method of my AsyncTask classes JSONParse,JSONParse1, JSONPArse2 as I need to retrieve the values of 3 variables from 3 different URL's concurrently.

However, values of only 3rd url are being set in all the three TextViews and the rest of the values are either being overwritten, discarded or ignored.

Please guide me as to how should I run these three API calls concurrently and display correct results.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
         Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
                        new JSONParse().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"JSONParse() ");
                        new JSONParse1().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"JSONParse1() ");
                        new JSONParse2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"JSONParse1() ");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ELSE Inside thread");
                        new JSONParse().execute();
                    }
```

}});
}

My AsyncTask class JSONParse is as follows:

```
   private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
 @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
}
 @Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
   json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);

 return json1;
               }
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json1) {

String jsonString = json1.getString("Sample");
 uid.setText(jsonString );
                        }  
  }
```

and so are JSONParse1 and JSONParse2 .

My AsyncTask class JSONParse is as follows:

```
   private class JSONParse1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
 @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
}
 @Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
   json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url3);

 return json2;
               }
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json1) {
String jsonString = json2.getString("Sample");
 name.setText(jsonString );
                        }  
  }
```

This is my JSONParse2

```
  private class JSONParse2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        value= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);
    }
     @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
       json3 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url3);

     return json3;
                   }
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json3) {

    String jsonString = json3.getString("Sample");
     value.setText(jsonString );
     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you taken all textview ids same. Take different id then try..
android:id="@+id/uid"...try to change it for all textViews

Comment: I was also facing the same issue .. But now ii is resolved by just changing the ids....

Answer (score 0):

In all the three class `JSONParse`, `JSONParse1` and `JSONParse2` you are finding `TextView` from `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);` secondly you are using `value` variable in all three classes which is definitely declared in your `mainActivity` class as it is not declared in any of 3 class.